# MySQLi PHP -> LEFT JOIN Returns Null when using fetch array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

I am currently creating a MySQLi PHP forum, and i'm having some problems with the MySQL LEFT JOINs, i am trying to get all the subforums "joined" with the set catid,

the query itself works fine when testing it in mysql workbench, and i receive the correct list. but whenever i try to put the results into an array, i get null

My current codelooks like this

```
$sql = 'SELECT `c`.`id`, `c`.`name`, `sc`.`id_sub`, `sc`.`name_sub`, `sc`.`catid` 
    FROM `forum_categories` AS `c` 
    LEFT JOIN `forum_subcategories` AS `sc` 
    ON `c`.`id` = `sc`.`catid`';
$stmt = $mysqli->query($sql);
$forum_categories = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch_array(FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   // define forum category
$forum_categories[$row['id']] = array(
    'title' => $row['name'],
);

    // add forums to category
$forum_categories[$row['id']]['forum_subcategories'][] = array(
    'id' => $row['id_sub'],
    'title' => $row['name_sub']
);
}

var_dump ($row->name);
```

But the var_dump just returns null.

This is what the var_dump($stmt); returns

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(10) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Comment: move var_dump just above closing }

Comment: why you're dumping $row->name instead of categories?

Comment: `var_dump ($stmt);` or `print_r($stmt);` immediately after the query to get the results immediately. don't wait until after you've run through all the fetch's to check the last row which may be empty. after you get that state accomplished, dump or print $row at the top of the while so you can see what's happening at that stage. it will get easier to "do a quick check" at the end when you are more familiar with the mysqli functions and properties, but for now ... baby steps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli **never** interfere with your queries.

If fetch_array returned null, then there are no rows left in resultset.

Comment: But when running the query in mysqlworkbench, i get the correct result?

Comment: well you are running your workbench against other database, or query is not the same. Or you actually get correct result from mysqli either but for some reason don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `var_dump()` is outside the `while` loop. As `while` exits when `fetch_array` returns `false`, the value of `$row` is `false` at the end of loop.

Comment: Why `-1` ??? some people should get banned for giving `-1` without reason. Or for not giving the reason in comment as it is said in rules of `StackOverflow`.